# Codeigniter is not decoding email address

Tags: php, codeigniter, urldecode

I am sending my email address through a form which is submitted by ajax to controller and the data for the ajax is created by this function:

```
// Function "serializeToJson" - Serialize form data, merge new object and returns json object
function serializeToJson(element, newObj){
    // Serialize form and split into Json Object
    var data = element.serialize().split("&");
    var object = {};
    for(var key in data){
        object[data[key].split("=")[0]] = data[key].split("=")[1];
    }

    // Merge new json obj to existing json object
    const target = {};
    $.extend(target, newObj, object);

    // return the final json object
    return target;
}
```

and in my ajax

```
data : serializeToJson(SUform, {action:'process_signup'}),
```

**The email which is being sent through the form is getting urlencoded i.e.**

> xxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com

the **%40** should be decoded to **@** when i receive the data in my controller.
In my controller i have set the following form validation rules for email:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
```

**The error:**

> The Email field must contain a valid email address

**What i want?**

Is there any way by which i can urldecode the email in form validation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
trim|urldecode|valid_email
```

It should work as the docs say you can use any php function as a "rule" and it will apply.

You'll still have to `urldecode` it again for when you put it in the database.

Comment: Thank you very much for instant solution.I have read the user guide but for me i was not looking at those lines